# Trouble with random number guessing game in c#

Tags: c#

So I am working on a project for school that in a guessing game for a randomly generated number between 1-100.  The only trouble I am having at the moment is that every time the user enters a new number the generated number also changes.  I tried putting the code to generate the number in the form loader but then I can't access it later in the program.  Here's what I have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int userGuess;
            userGuess = int.Parse(guessText.Text);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int number = rand.Next(1, 100);

                label2.Text = "" + number;


                    if (userGuess > number)
                    {
                        resultLabel.Text = "Your guess is too high";
                    }

                    else if (userGuess < number)
                    {
                        resultLabel.Text = "Your guess is too low.";
                    }

            else if (userGuess == number)
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "That is correct!";
            }

                guessText.Clear();



        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx

Comment: The form loader is the correct place to put it.  Look up what fields and member variables are.

Comment: @MobyDisk It wouldn't work if the form is closed and opened, the random number would still regenerate every time.

Comment: When I move it into the form loader and try to compile it tells me that the name 'number' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: That's because you're moving the declaration as well as the assignment into the `Form1_Load` method. Declaring the variable on the class level will make it accesible from both `Form1_Load` and `guessButton_Click` @TimKister

Comment: @TimKister Please review the answer I gave.

Comment: @cybermonkey: It isn't clear from the question, but I think that is what Tim wants.  Tim: You want a new number generated every time you open and close the form, but not every time the user clicks the button, right?

Comment: @MobyDisk yes, I want them to have as many guesses as they need for each number that gets generated.  If they guess too high or low I want the program to tell them and give them more tries.

Comment: I've got it mostly working now but everytime the number is set to 0.  I declared the int number in the public partial class but it seems to be stuck to zero because I can't set it to be random at that time.

Comment: @TimKister I created a temporary `C#` project with your code, repaired the code, and then edited my answer to include the correct code. I also checked that it generates the random number properly, and it does. Please review my answer and if it solves your problem completely, please mark it as 'accepted'.

Comment: So are you clear on member variables -vs- local variables now?  You have two examples on how to initialize them.

Comment: I think so, the member variables are the ones declared in the public class Form1 in this instance.  Those are usable throughout the program.  Whereas a local variable is declared in a private class like the click_button event and those can only be accessed while that class is running?

Comment: *With respect to your code and all the current answers' code*, **do not** use `rand.Next(1, 100)` if you want a random number between 1 and 100 (inclusive). It will never land on 100.  Use `rand.Next(1, 101)`, which will. Also, do not assign a new `Random` object in your event handler; initialize a `Random` class member with your form, or you will compromise `Random`'s (pseudo)randomness. See MSDN for details on `Next(int, int)`'s inclusive lower and exclusive upper bounds, also on using the same instance of `Random` across calls to `Next` for proper (pseudo)randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it currently stands, the `Random` number is overwritten *every time the `guessButton_Click` function is run*.

You are declaring `Random` inside the `guessButton_Click` function, that is called **every time the `guess` button is clicked** (that's also a memory leak!).
To fix, declare it as a global variable, in the namespace:

**Edit:** The below code compiles properly, and works perfectly.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int number = new Random().Next(1, 100);
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int userGuess;
            userGuess = int.Parse(guessText.Text);
            label2.Text = "" + number;


            if (userGuess > number)
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "Your guess is too high";
            }

            else if (userGuess < number)
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "Your guess is too low.";
            }

            else if (userGuess == number)
            {
                resultLabel.Text = "That is correct!";
            }

            guessText.Clear();



        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @cybermonkey, that worked wonderfully.  I would upvote you but this is my first day on the site and it won't let me yet.  I did click the check mark for you though.

Comment: +1. No downvotes on your answer (at least now). After a certain amount of rep (I think it's 2,000), SO gives you the breakdown of up and downvotes. Right now this answer is at +2 / -0.

Comment: I don't think it's a memory leak as the memory will be reclaimed by the GC.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a new random number every button click try the following:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    Random rand;
    int number;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rand = new Random();
        number = rand.Next(1, 100);
    }

    private void guessButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userGuess;
        userGuess = int.Parse(guessText.Text);

        label2.Text = "" + number;


        if (userGuess > number)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Your guess is too high";
        }

        else if (userGuess < number)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "Your guess is too low.";
        }

        else if (userGuess == number)
        {
            resultLabel.Text = "That is correct!";
        }

        guessText.Clear();
    }


}
```

Comment: This fixed the problem of it always changing the number, but now it seems to be always set to 0. I tried to initialize number to rand.Next(1, 100) in the public class but it doesn't allow that.

Comment: It works fine for me.  What is the bug?  This example works as a clearer example since the work is done in the constructor rather than in the declaration.

Comment: I have made the program myself but I didn't experience any problems  the number wasn't set to 0 every time for me

Comment: @Sybren With your code, the random number is always set to 0, probably because the compiler didn't know it was a number.

Comment: Try to run this code and you will get a new random number every time.

Comment: @Sybren As mentioned before, I *did* run your code, and I got that error.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2013 and I don't get any errors and I'm not able to reproduce your error.

Comment: @Sybren So do I, the version of Visual Studio doesn't make a difference. As said in an earlier comment, *the compiler doesn't know it's a number*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62898/discussion-between-sybren-and-cybermonkey).